# Add an interface to a class afterwards

Tags: delphi, oop, model-view-controller, interface

Is it possible to add and implement an interface to an already existing class (which is a descendant of `TInterfaced` or `TInterfacedPersistent`) to accomplish separating Model and View into 2 units?

A small explanation why I need something like this:

I am developing a tree-structure, open-type model, which has following structure (VERY simplified and incomplete, just to illustrate the outline of the problem):

**Database_Kernel.pas**

```
TVMDNode = class(TInterfacedPersistent);
public
  class function ClassGUID: TGUID; virtual; abstract; // constant. used for RTTI

  property RawData: TBytes {...};
  constructor Create(ARawData: TBytes);

  function GetParent: TVMDNode;
  function GetChildNodes: TList<TVMDNode>;
end;
```

**Vendor_Specific_Stuff.pas**

```
TImageNode = class(TVMDNode)
public
  class function ClassGUID: TGUID; override; // constant. used for RTTI

  // Will be interpreted out of the raw binary data of the inherited class
  property Image: TImage {...};
end;

TUTF8Node = class(TVMDNode)
public
  class function ClassGUID: TGUID; override; // constant. used for RTTI

  // Will be interpreted out of the raw binary data of the inherited class
  property StringContent: WideString {...};
end;

TContactNode = class(TVMDNode)
public
  class function ClassGUID: TGUID; override; // constant. used for RTTI

  // Will be interpreted out of the raw binary data of the inherited class
  property PreName: WideString {...};
  property FamilyName: WideString {...};
  property Address: WideString {...};
  property Birthday: TDate {...};
end;
```

Using a GUID-based RTTI (which uses `ClassGUID`), the function `GetChildNodes` is able to find the matching class and initialize it with the raw data. (Each dataset contains `ClassGUID` and `RawData` beside other data like created/updated timestamps)

It is important to notice that my API (`Database_Kernel.pas`) is strictly separated from the vendor's node classes (`Vendor_Specific_Stuff.pas`).

---

A vendor-specific program's GUI wants to visualize the nodes, e.g. giving them an user-friendly name, an icon etc.

Following idea works:

```
IGraphicNode = interface(IInterface)
  function Visible: boolean;
  function Icon: TIcon;
  function UserFriendlyName: string;
end;
```

The vendor's specific descendants of `TVMDNode` in `Vendor_Specific_Stuff.pas` will implement the `IGraphicNode` interface.

But the vendor also needs to change `Database_Kernel.pas` to implement `IGraphicNode` to the base node class `TVMDNode` (which is used for "unknown" nodes, where RTTI was unable to find the matching class of the dataset, so at least the binary raw data can be read using `TVMDNode.RawData`).

So he will change my class as follows:

```
TVMDNode = class(TInterfacedPersistent, IGraphicNode);
public
  property RawData: TBytes {...};
  class function ClassGUID: TGUID; virtual; abstract; // constant. used for RTTI
  constructor Create(ARawData: TBytes);
  function GetParent: TVMDNode;
  function GetChildNodes: TList<TVMDNode>;

  // --- IGraphicNode
  function Visible: boolean; virtual; // default behavior for unknown nodes: False
  function Icon: TIcon; virtual; // default behavior for unknown nodes: "?" icon
  function UserfriendlyName: string; virtual; // default behavior for unknown nodes: "Unknown"
end;
```

The problem is that `IGraphicNode` is vendor/program-specific and should not be in the API's `Database_Kernel.pas`, since GUI and Model/API should be strictly divided.

My wish would be that the interace `IGraphicNode` could be added and implemented to the existing `TVMDNode` class (which is already a descendant of `TInterfacedPersistent` to allow interfaces) in a separate unit. As far as I know, Delphi does not support something like this.

Beside the fact that it is not nice to mix Model and View in one single unit/class, there will be following real-world problem: If the vendor has to change my `Database_Kernel.pas` API to extend `TVMDNode` with the `IGraphicNode` interface, he needs to re-do all his changes, as soon as I release a new version of my API `Database_Kernel.pas`.

What should I do? I thought very long about possible solutions possible with Delphi's OOP. A workaround may be nesting TVMDNode's into a container class, which has a secondary RTTI, so after I have found the `TVMDNode` class, I could search for a `TVMDNodeGUIContainer` class. But this sounds very strangle and like a dirty hack.

PS: This API is an OpenSource/GPL project. I am trying to stay compatible with old generations of Delphi (e.g. 6), since I want to maximize the number of possible users. However, if a solution of the problem above is only possible with the new generation of Delphi languages, I might consider dropping Delphi 6 support for this API.

Comment: I don't know why someone down-voted you, but your question looks valid to me. +1 from me for posting something interesting.

Comment: @FunctionR I wondered about it too, since question downvotes are usually only for [bad research](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94757/261735). Maybe my question was too long (however, the title describes it in one sentence). I tend to explain why I need something to avoid comments like "Why do you need it? Nobody needs to do that."

Comment: The vendor cannot derive a new class from TVMDNode?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The RTTI algorithm `GetChildNodes` looks for a matching class which has the same class-GUID as the dataset. If it doesn't find any matching class, it will create an instance of `TVMDNode` (which should be shown in the GUI as "unknown node"). The algorithm does not know that a vendor did use a derivation of `TVMDNode` (also since it is in another unit) to express that the node class is unknown (last resort).

Comment: @rinn - I don't understand the difference between putting `TGraphicNode = class(TVMDNode)` in 'vendor_specific_stuff.pas' and putting `IGraphicNode = interface(IInterface)` together with `TVendorVMDNode = class(TVMDNode, IGraphicNode)` in 'vendor_specific_stuff.pas'. Probably I lost it, you don't have to mind.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I thank you for taking time to look at this (a bit complicated) problem. Both of your possibilities do work. Either using an interface `IGraphicNode` or using a  shared derivate `TGraphicVMDNode`. Both work for all of the vendor's extensions. The only problem is the case when the RTTI algorithm in `TVMDNode.GetChildNodes` can't find the exact class, so it instanciates an object using `TVMDNode.Create` as last resort. This object is then not a derivate of `TGraphicVMDNode` of the vendor, and therefore it cannot be shown in the GUI of the program.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz If I would use a derivate `TGraphicVMDNode` instead of an interface, the problem will be following: The GUI looks at the result of `GetChildNodes` and recognizes that some of these nodes are not a derivate of `TGraphicVMDNode` . Instead of calling `node.Icon` or `node.UserFriendlyName` , the GUI needs to choose hard-coded default-values for these items. This doesn't sound like a good OO-design to me, since these default values are already defined in `TGraphicVMDNode`. There seems also no possibility "casting" a `TVMDNode` into a `TGraphicVMDNode`, which would be a good workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve the ability to persist data and implement it through inheritance and still create the correct instances for the ClassGUIDs stored in the tables if you'd apply the [factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

For each node class there would be one class factory (or just a function pointer) responsible for creation of the correct Delphi class. Class factories may register themselves in the unit initialization section (once per application startup) at the kernel singleton object.

The kernel singleton would then map GUID to correct factory that would in turn call the correct class instance constructor (as shown at http://delphipatterns.blog.com/2011/03/23/abstract-factory)

Packages may be split into separate DLLs and classes implemented in separate units, still inheriting from one base TVMNode class.

The features you now use RTTI for can be supported in descendant classes or in the factory classes easily through some virtual methods.

You might also consider using simpler [Data Transfer Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978717.aspx) for saving/loading the TVMNodes and perhaps take some inspiration from an already well perceived [Object Relational Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) or a [Object Persistence framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_persistence) as the problem you are trying to solve seem to me like exactly the problems they are handling (already)

I don't know about good Delphi open source frameworks of this class. But from other languages you can look at [Java Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29), [Microsoft .NET Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_framework) or minimalistic [Google Protocol Buffers serializer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protobuf)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This idea works. :-) Technically, the class was not extended by an interface, but the Kernel was told to return the extended class for GUID "X", so all new objects are of the extended type instead of the original one. Btw, which tool did you use to create this UML diagram?

Comment: @rinntech in your problem some UML modeling (before coding) seems the right thing to do. Also some sequence or activity diagrams might help you get things clarified. For the drawing I used [Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/11) - it is not free, besides reverse engineering and code generation it "knows" how correct UML diagrams look and does all the drawing itself. I just have to say what I want to put into the model, the look of the picture is automatically generated to be UML compliant. It is top #1 UML tool as far as I know (trial available)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.

We implemented something similar to gain control of global/singletons for testing purposes. We changed our singletons to be accessible as interfaces on the application (not `TApplication`, our own equivalent). Then we added the ability to dynamically add/remove interfaces at run-time. Now our test cases are able to plug in suitable mocks as and when needed.

I'll describe the general approach, hopefully you'll be able to apply it to the specifics of your situation.

1. Add a field to hold a list of dynamically added interface. An `TInterfaceList` works nicely.
2. Add methods to add/remove the dynamic interfaces.
3. Override `function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; virtual;`. Your implementation will first check the interface list, and if not found will defer to the base implementation.

---

#### Edit: Sample Code

To answer your question:

> I understand that the class now can tell others that it supports interface X now, so the interface was ADDED during runtime. But I also need to IMPLEMENT the interface's methods from outside (another unit). How is this done?

When you add the interface, you're adding an instance of the object that implements the interface. This is very much like the normal **property** ... **implements** *<interface>* technique to delegate implementation of an interface to another object. The key difference being this is dynamic. As such it will have the same kinds of limitations: E.g. no access to the "host" unless explicitly given a reference.

The following DUnit test case demonstrates a simplified version of the technique in action.

```
unit tdDynamicInterfaces;

interface

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  TestFramework;

type
  TTestDynamicInterfaces = class(TTestCase)
  published
    procedure TestUseDynamicInterface;
  end;

type
  ISayHello = interface
    ['{6F6DDDE3-F9A5-407E-B5A4-CDF91791A05B}']
    function SayHello: string;
  end;

implementation

{ ImpGlobal }

type
  TDynamicInterfaces = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterface)
  { We must explicitly state that we are implementing IInterface so that
    our implementation of QueryInterface is used. }
  private
    FDynamicInterfaces: TInterfaceList;
  protected
    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AddInterface(AImplementedInterface: IInterface);
  end;

type
  TImplementor = class (TInterfacedObject, ISayHello)
  { NOTE: This could easily have been implemented in a separate unit. }
  protected
    {ISayHello}
    function SayHello: string;
  end;

{ TDynamicInterfaces }

procedure TDynamicInterfaces.AddInterface(AImplementedInterface: IInterface);
begin
  { The simplest, but least flexible approach (see also QueryInterface).
    Other options entail tagging specific GUIDs to be associated with given
    implementation instance. Then it becomes feasible to check for duplicates
    and also dynamically remove specific interfaces. }
  FDynamicInterfaces.Add(AImplementedInterface);
end;

constructor TDynamicInterfaces.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FDynamicInterfaces := TInterfaceList.Create;
end;

destructor TDynamicInterfaces.Destroy;
begin
  FDynamicInterfaces.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TDynamicInterfaces.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
var
  LIntf: IInterface;
begin
  { This implementation basically means the first implementor added will be 
    returned in cases where multiple implementors support the same interface. }
  for LIntf in FDynamicInterfaces do
  begin
    if Supports(LIntf, IID, Obj) then
    begin
      Result := S_OK;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  Result := inherited QueryInterface(IID, Obj);
end;

{ TImplementor }

function TImplementor.SayHello: string;
begin
  Result := 'Hello. My name is, ' + ClassName;
end;

{ TTestDynamicInterfaces }

procedure TTestDynamicInterfaces.TestUseDynamicInterface;
var
  LDynamicInterfaceObject: TDynamicInterfaces;
  LInterfaceRef: IUnknown;
  LFriend: ISayHello;
  LActualResult: string;
begin
  LActualResult := '';

  { Use ObjRef for convenience to not declare interface with "AddInterface" }
  LDynamicInterfaceObject := TDynamicInterfaces.Create;
  { But lifetime is still managed by the InterfaceRef. }
  LInterfaceRef := LDynamicInterfaceObject;

  { Comment out the next line to see what happens when support for 
    interface is not dynamically added. }
  LDynamicInterfaceObject.AddInterface(TImplementor.Create);

  if Supports(LInterfaceRef, ISayHello, LFriend) then
  begin
    LFriend := LInterfaceRef as ISayHello;
    LActualResult := LFriend.SayHello;
  end;

  CheckEqualsString('Hello. My name is, TImplementor', LActualResult);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I need to try this later. I understand that the class now can tell others that it supports interface X now, so the interface was ADDED during runtime. But I also need to IMPLEMENT the interface's methods from outside (another unit).  How is this done?

Comment: @rinntech I've updated with sample code. Hopefully this clarifies your concern about how the actual _implementation_ works.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it out and it worked. However, there is one part which I don't think it is clean and which destroys all the sense of the dynamicly added interfaces. At the line `ANode.AddDynamicInterface(LImplGraphicalNode)` I need to get a
`LImplGraphicalNode` (of type `TGraphicalNode`) with the same data of `ANode` (of type `TVMDNode`). Since I cannot "cast" a `TVMDNode` object into a `TGraphicalNode` node, the only possibility to accomplish this is this is creating a clone: `LImplGraphicalNode := TGraphicalNode.Create('garbage'); LImplGraphicalNode.Assign(ANode);` .

Comment: But this has 2 disadvantages: (1) I don't like that the whole object gets copied, since it is not good for performance and memory usage. (2) Since I now have a `LImplGraphicalNode` object, I don't need all that stuff with dynamic interfaces, I just can use `Caption := LImplGraphicalNode.Caption` , so it does not make any sense to use dynamic interfaces . (The dynamicly added interfaces had the intention to use the `TVMDNode` object as `TGraphicalNode` without copying using `Assign`).

Can you please tell me what I did wrong? My MCVE code is here: http://pastebin.com/9FyfJjsz . Thank you.

Comment: @rinntech First your implementor doesn't _have to be_ a `TGraphicNode` instance. That's the beauty of interfaces - they have zero implementation dependencies. (Of course you might choose to inherit from `TGraphicNode` if it makes your implementation easier - the point is you're not forced to.) Second instead of copying the data, you can just create your implementor with a reference to `ANode`.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand it. Could you please tell me what I need to change? (1) How can it work without having an `TGraphicNode` instance? `TGraphicNode` is the implementation which I need to define, otherwise the `TVMDNode` would only know that it implements the IID identifier, but has no code for it. (2) How can I create my implementor `TGraphicNode` with "reference" to `ANode`, like you said? `ANode` is of type `TVMDNode` (which is the ancestor class of `TGraphicNode`). How can I use `TVMDNode` as `TGraphicNode`?

Comment: @rinntech You defined an `IGraphicNode` interface. Any class that declares `Visible`, `Icon` and `UserFriendlyName` as defined in your interface can implement that interface. It doesn't have to inherit from `TGraphicalNode` at all (if you don't want to).

Comment: @rinntech You can define `TMyGraphicNodeImplementor = class(TInterfacedObject)`. With a field to reference your node. The constructor can take a node as a parameter, then you call `TMyGraphicNodeImplementor.Create(ANode)`. But really this is moving into an entirely different question now....

Comment: Hm... I don't think that it is moving to a different question. Your solution using a wrapper implementor does only solve the problem particulary. The initial question was, how to accomplish it, that another unit extends (adds+implements) `TVMDNode` by a functionality of an interface `IGraphicalNode`. By having a `TMyGraphicNodeImplementor` which just **wraps** a `TVMDNode`, I can have extended functionality, BUT these added functions are not able to access e.g. `strict protected` fields of the `TVMDNode`, which would have been possible if the interface would have been added in design-time.

Comment: @rinntech Your question asked how to add an interface to a class at runtime (as opposed to compile time). I have demonstrated exactly how to achieve that. In my answer I pointed out that the technique is similar to to the compile time option of delegating implementation of an interface to an independent object using **property implements**: The delegate does not automatically have access to the "host". Any extra information/methods you want the delegate to access, you need to explicitly make available. You are now asking how to do this - and there are many techniques to do so.

Comment: In my original post I never mentioned "runtime". It does not matter if it is done in runtime or compile time, but the added implementation must be able to access protected fields, like it would be possible if I would add the interface directly by editing the API unit.

Comment: @rinntech In your original post you never mentioned the word "protected" once - not even incidentally in your sample code. However the only "afterwards" that applies to a class's definition is "not compile-time" in other words "run-time". Delphi does not support redefining a class at all. The closest available feature in _recent_ versions of Delphi is class helpers which don't change the class at all, but make it possible to call new methods as if they were declared on the class.