# Interface delegation + overriding

Tags: delphi, oop, interface, delegation

Due to the lack of multiple inheritance in Delphi, I need to work with interface delegation. This is a very new topic to me and I have a problem with combining overridding with interface delegation.

The class `TMyNode` must inherit from `TBaseClass` and needs to implement `IAddedStuff` . I want to have the default implementation of all functions of `IAddedStuff` in `TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation` , so I don't need to have duplicate code for getters/setters everywhere. So, I have delegated those things using `DefaultBehavior` .

The problem is, that `TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation` is meant to have virtual methods, so I want to override them directly in `TMyNode` . This does work if I write `FDefaultImplementation: TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation;` instead of `FDefaultImplementation: IAddedStuff;` .

But now, for some reasons `TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation` will increase the Ref-Counter for `x: TBaseClass;`, so it cannot be freed. What should I do?

My simplified reproduction code is below:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  IAddedStuff = interface(IInterface)
  ['{9D5B00D0-E317-41A7-8CC7-3934DF785A39}']
    function GetCaption: string; {virtual;}
  end;

  TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation = class(TInterfacedObject, IAddedStuff)
    function GetCaption: string; virtual;
  end;

  TBaseClass = class(TInterfacedObject);

  TMyNode = class(TBaseClass, IAddedStuff)
  private
    FDefaultImplementation: TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation;
  public
    property DefaultBehavior: TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation read FDefaultImplementation
      write FDefaultImplementation implements IAddedStuff;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    // -- IAddedStuff
    // Here are some functions which I want to "override" in TMyNode.
    // All functions not declared here, should be taken from FDefaultImplementation .
    function GetCaption: string; {override;}
  end;

{ TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation }

function TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation.GetCaption: string;
begin
  result := 'PROBLEM: CAPTION NOT OVERRIDDEN';
end;

{ TMyNode }

destructor TMyNode.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FDefaultImplementation) then
  begin
    FDefaultImplementation.Free;
    FDefaultImplementation := nil;
  end;

  inherited;
end;

function TMyNode.GetCaption: string;
begin
  Result := 'OK: Caption overridden';
end;

var
  x: TBaseClass;
  gn: IAddedStuff;
  s: string;
begin
  x := TMyNode.Create;
  try
    TMyNode(x).DefaultBehavior := TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation.Create;
    Assert(Supports(x, IAddedStuff, gn));
    WriteLn(gn.GetCaption);
  finally
    WriteLn('RefCount = ', x.RefCount);
    // x.Free; // <-- FREE fails since FRefCount is 1
  end;
  ReadLn(s);
end.
```

Comment: Im not familiar with interfaces but I have a question. `TMyNode` inherits of `TBaseClass` and `IAddedStuff`. `TBaseClass` inherits of `TInterfacedObject`, `TAddedStuffDef....` inherits also of `TInterfacedObject` and `IAddedStuff` So basicly if TMyNode inherits of `TAddedStuffDef....` shouldnt it have the same set of functions? Seems double to me but maybe im wrong :)

Comment: TMyNode needs to inherit from TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation AND TBaseClass . Since multiple inheritance is not possible,  I need to do all the stuff above. :-( In my simplified example TBaseClass has just no additional content because it us irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Implementing_Interfaces#Implementing_Interfaces_by_Delegation on how to implement delegation (with examples)

Comment: @mjn I already read that twice. I tried for hours to find a solution which works and doesn't crash.

Comment: The documentation uses interfaces whereas your code uses class references - mixing this is a frequent source for reference counting headaches.

Comment: @mjn I know the differences between my code and the code at Embarcadero. I made several experiments since I additionally wanted to have methods overridden, which is not mentioned at the docwiki. When I have `private FDefaultImplementation: TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation;` , the overridding works but the reference counting messes up. If I use `private FDefaultImplementation: IAddedStuffDefaultImplementation;` , then the reference counting works but the overridding does not work anymore.

Comment: @mjn If I EXACTLY use Embarcadero's example code at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Implementing_Interfaces#Delegating_to_a_Class-Type_Property and simply add a MyClass.Free; at the end, I will get a "Invalid pointer operation" too (because the reference counter is not zero). So, is their code wrong too, or should this object never be freed?

Comment: Anchestors of TInterfacedObject are reference counted (unless you change this) and should never be freed.

Comment: @uweraabe I thought it depends if I declare the thing as object or interface.  interfaces are reference counted,  objects not. The second (!) example of embarcadero declared `var MyClass: TMyClass; begin MyClass := TMyClass.Create;` so this is definitely an usage as object and should not be reference counted.  or am I completely wrong?

Comment: OK, let me clarify. Achestors of TInterfacedObject implement interfaces with reference counting and the lifetime of those object instances is controlled by the reference counting of these interfaces. You should never use Free on such objects. This is different to TInterfacedPersistent, which doesn't implement reference counting.

Comment: @UweRaabe Thanks for your reply. Can you please look at this example and tell me why FastMM4 is warning me about memory leaks, when I am not using `.Free` on a `TInterfacedObject`-derivate? Should I ignore these warnings? http://pastebin.com/LetDgvhr

Comment: When he said you should never call `Free` on them he rather meant you should not mix object and interface references because as soon as you assign a `TInterfacedObject` derivative to an interface or call Supports on it the reference counting will kick in causing this instance to be freed when no interface reference to it is active any more. Since it is in fact very unlikely that you never assign a `TInterfacedObject` (or inherited class) instance to an interface reference (that is why you inherited from that class in the first place, right?) you in fact will never have to call `Free` on it.

Comment: Ok, I think I have understood it. But just to be sure: is it correct to call `a.Free` (a: TInterfacedObject) and `c.Free` (c: TObject) in my minimal example http://pastebin.com/LetDgvhr ? The only thing which is "forbidden", is to do something which will increase the ref-counter of `a` or `c`. I am trying to understand Embarcadero's example http://pastebin.com/mvfVS18R . They seem to have done something incorrectly, so I have either a memory leak (according to FastMM4) or a crash because the ref-counter is not zero when trying to call `Free`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are delegating the `IAddedStuff` then you should also implement non-default behavior on another class and pass it by constructor injection.

Also if you are mixing object and interface references, make sure the ref counting does not conflict. When using interface delegation the reference of the container object gets changed.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

type
  IAddedStuff = interface(IInterface)
  ['{9D5B00D0-E317-41A7-8CC7-3934DF785A39}']
    function GetCaption: string; {virtual;}
  end;

  TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation = class(TInterfacedObject, IAddedStuff)
    function GetCaption: string; virtual;
  end;

  TAddedStuffOverriddenImplementation = class(TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation)
    function GetCaption: string; override;
  end;

  TBaseClass = class(TInterfacedPersistent);

  TMyNode = class(TBaseClass, IAddedStuff)
  private
    FAddedStuff: IAddedStuff;
    property AddedStuff: IAddedStuff read FAddedStuff implements IAddedStuff;
  public
    constructor Create(const addedStuff: IAddedStuff);
  end;

{ TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation }

function TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation.GetCaption: string;
begin
  result := 'PROBLEM: CAPTION NOT OVERRIDDEN';
end;

{ TAddedStuffOverriddenImplementation }

function TAddedStuffOverriddenImplementation.GetCaption: string;
begin
  Result := 'OK: Caption overridden';
end;

{ TMyNode }

constructor TMyNode.Create;
begin
  FAddedStuff := addedStuff;
end;

var
  x: TBaseClass;
  gn: IAddedStuff;
begin
  x := TMyNode.Create(TAddedStuffOverriddenImplementation.Create);
  try
    Assert(Supports(x, IAddedStuff, gn));
    WriteLn(gn.GetCaption);
  finally
    x.Free;
  end;
  Readln;
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
end.
```

**Edit:**

After the discussion in the comments I would suggest the following:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils;

type
  IAddedStuff = interface(IInterface)
  ['{9D5B00D0-E317-41A7-8CC7-3934DF785A39}']
    function GetCaption: string;
  end;

  TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation = class(TInterfacedObject, IAddedStuff)
    function GetCaption: string; virtual;
  end;

  TBaseClass = class(TInterfacedPersistent);

  TMyNode = class(TBaseClass, IAddedStuff)
  private
    FAddedStuff: IAddedStuff;
    property AddedStuff: IAddedStuff read FAddedStuff implements IAddedStuff;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

  TAddedStuffOverriddenImplementation = class(TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation)
  private
    FMyNode: TMyNode;
  public
    constructor Create(AMyNode: TMyNode);
    function GetCaption: string; override;
  end;

{ TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation }

function TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation.GetCaption: string;
begin
  result := 'PROBLEM: CAPTION NOT OVERRIDDEN';
end;

{ TMyNode }

constructor TMyNode.Create;
begin
  FAddedStuff := TAddedStuffOverriddenImplementation.Create(Self);
end;

{ TAddedStuffOverriddenImplementation }

constructor TAddedStuffOverriddenImplementation.Create(AMyNode: TMyNode);
begin
  FMyNode := AMyNode;
end;

function TAddedStuffOverriddenImplementation.GetCaption: string;
begin
  Result := 'OK: Caption overridden';
end;


var
  x: TBaseClass;
  gn: IAddedStuff;
begin
  x := TMyNode.Create;
  try
    Assert(Supports(x, IAddedStuff, gn));
    WriteLn(gn.GetCaption);
  finally
    x.Free;
  end;
  ReadLn;
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.

I did mix object and interface references, because this was the only possibility to make the "override" work. For some reasons, the overridden variant will be called if the private field is an object reference, but not when it is an interface reference.

Comment: Your code solves the problem with the reference counting, but alas  `TAddedStuffOverriddenImplementation` has no access to `TMyNode` .

The idea behind this is that `TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation.GetCaptions` just outputs "Unknown" (something constant), while `TMyNode.GetCaption` outputs something data specific like "User: Thomas" . Is there any other option I have to have `GetCaption` inside `TMyNode`, but still overriding the default implementation of the interface (which is mainly getter and setters as well as "unknown" captions+icons)?

Comment: Did you create the `TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation` to reuse it in different other classes without the need to implement `IAddedStuff` every time? Otherwise you can put the default implementation methods just fine in a `TBaseClassWithAddedStuff`, make them virtual and then override them in your `TMyNode`.

Comment: Yes, the purpose of `TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation` is to share it with all classes, so that they don't need to implement 20 dummy methods if they don't support something specific. Alas, I cannot modify `TBaseClass`, since I need to split API and vendor-specific-addons in 2 units . This problem here is a follow-up-problem which happened when I tried to fix this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24439228/3544341 .

Comment: In [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HI5jD.png) you can see that (example) `TGraphicImageNode` and `TContactImageNode` implement both `IGraphicNode` . In the real project, much more classes will implement this interface, but the problem is, that 90% of the code is just the default code which won't be overridden and should be the default-implementation. I fear I have reached the limits of OOP in Delphi.

Comment: In your question you assigned the `TAddedStuffDefaultImplementation` via a property. Is passing it from outside a requirement or could the class create it in its constructor?

Comment: I do not require to set that default implementation from outside. The class could set it itself. I am sorry that those things are not clear from the OP. It is not easy to describe and simplify such a complex problem without forgetting requirements/limits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This trick works for me. I have made a small improvement, too: I moved the code from `TMyNode.Create` to `TMyNode.AfterConstruction` . This way I can be sure that it will be always executed. In my case, I would have needed to make the constructors virtual, otherwise `FAddedStuff` wouldn't have been initialized.